# Is it possible to create .ipa file local with phonegap?

Tags: ios, cordova, ipa

I am working on a automatic process to build and sign my app local for android and ios. I already created successfully the signed .apk file for android. Now I am trying to *create the .ipa file locally*, without using Adobe PhoneGap Build.

All the necessary key-files are available. The online build over Adobe PhoneGap Build is working for both plattforms andorid/ios.

Note:- My powershell/cmd script is written and performed on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a mac os to deploy the .ipa file locally.
create the phonegap project as you have done in the windows machine and then build the app using

```
phonegap build ios
```

Then navigate to the folder platform > ios , you will find the xcodeproj, open it in the xcode and test it in the ios devices if necessary else go to the product tab in the xcode and choose the option archive then follow the steps to generate the .ipa file, provided all the necessary certificates,key-files have been installed and updated.

Its not possible to create .ipa file locally without a mac os.